# When the image under a real morphism is constructible?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a morphism $f:\Bbb{A}^n_{\Bbb{C}}\rightarrow\Bbb{A}^m_{\Bbb{C}}$ of complex affine spaces, Chevalley's theorem states that the image of a closed subvariety is *[constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_(topology))*, i.e. could be described with finitely many equations $f(y_1,\dots,y_m)=0$ and inequations $g(y_1,\dots,y_m)\neq 0$ combined with "and" & "or". On the other hand, over real numbers one must allow inequalities as well, e.g. the image of $$f:\Bbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{R}}\rightarrow\Bbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{R}}:x\mapsto x^2$$
is given by $x\geq 0$. Indeed, it is known that the image of a closed subvariety under a real morphism $f:\Bbb{A}^n_{\Bbb{R}}\rightarrow\Bbb{A}^m_{\Bbb{R}}$ is *[semialgebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set)*.

My question: Is there any criteria guaranteeing that the image of a closed subvariety under $f:\Bbb{A}^n_{\Bbb{R}}\rightarrow\Bbb{A}^m_{\Bbb{R}}$ is constructible so that one can avoid inequalities when it comes to describing the image?

Remark: I am interested only in the closed points; that's why I am discussing varieties.